# How to delete rows by date when time is unknown

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to delete rows for a given date from my table. Currently, it only works when I format it as follows:

```
delete from table_name 
where date_entered = to_date('20-SEP-15 11:10:35', 'dd-MON-yy hh:mi:ss');
```

If I leave out the time, it just returns "0 rows deleted". If there are a large number of entries from a given day that all occurred at different times, it isn't really feasible to enter the exact time for each one in order to delete them all, especially with time not being automatically visible.

Comment: so.... mysql, SQL Server or Oracle?, pick one

Comment: Just take the date part of the date and time value stored in the where criteria.

Comment: Use a date range using `BETWEEN`. That way it would use the index too. Using TRUNC or any function would suppress the index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `between` approach works but I prefer:

```
delete from table_name
where date_entered >= to_date('20-SEP-15', 'dd-MON-yy') 
and date_entered < to_date('21-SEP-15', 'dd-MON-yy');
```

Oracle converts to that form under the hood:

```
explain plan for
delete from table_name
where date_entered between to_date('20-SEP-15 00:00:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh:mi:ss') 
and to_date('20-SEP-15 23:59:59', 'dd-MON-yy hh:mi:ss');

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 4143694936

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | DELETE STATEMENT   |            |     1 |     9 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  DELETE            | TABLE_NAME |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   FILTER           |            |       |       |            |          |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN| INDEX_NAME |     1 |     9 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------


PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter(TO_DATE('20-SEP-15 23:59:59','dd-MON-yy 
              hh:mi:ss')>=TO_DATE('20-SEP-15 00:00:00','dd-MON-yy hh:mi:ss'))
   3 - access("DATE_ENTERED">=TO_DATE('20-SEP-15 00:00:00','dd-MON-yy 
              hh:mi:ss') AND "DATE_ENTERED"<=TO_DATE('20-SEP-15 23:59:59','dd-MON-yy 
              hh:mi:ss'))
```

... which is similar to the plan you'd get from my query; except it's using `<=` rather than `<`. The effect is the same (as long as it's a date field and not a timestamp).

Comment: Alex, good to see you are still actively contributing. Great going mate!

Answer (score 3):

you should delete by date range if you have a datetime field. Make sure not to wrap your field in a function to avoid a full table scan:

```
delete from table_name where 
date_entered between to_date('20-SEP-15 00:00:00', 'dd-MON-yy hh:mi:ss') 
                 and to_date('20-SEP-15 23:59:59', 'dd-MON-yy hh:mi:ss');
```

Assuming you do have an index on date_entered field.

Answer (score 0):

Use Oracle's `trunc()` function - it removes the time from a datetime value.

```
delete from table_name where trunc(date_entered) = to_date('20-SEP-15', 'dd-MON-yy');
```

Comment: If there is an index on `date_entered`, this (or any function call) will prevent that being used.

Comment: And - to expand and clarify Alex's observation: If the base table is very large and there is an index, the difference in execution times may be one or more orders of magnitude (rather than 10% or even 50%). Moreover, even without an index, just the repeated function calls to `trunc()` may increase execution times by nontrivial amounts.

Answer (score 0):

This is how date and timestamp literals looks like in ANSI/ISO SQL.
Most databases, if not all of them, support that syntax.

```
select    timestamp '2015-09-20 11:10:35'
         ,date '2015-09-20'

from      dual
;
```

Comment: "it isn't really feasible to enter the exact time for each one " - using a timestamp literal doesn't really help with that? (Comparing as `where date_entered = timestamp '2015-09-20 11:10:35'` woudl also stop any index being used, as the column date value would be converted to a timestamp for the comparison; unless you cast it: `where date_entered = cast(timestamp '2015-09-20 11:10:35' as date)`.

Comment: @AlexPoole - I believe all Dudu meant to point out was that the query could be written using - in this case - the ANSI date literal. My preference too; I would write it as `... where date_entered >= date '2015-09-20' and date_entered < date '2015-09-21'` (which is exactly the same as your solution except the different date literal syntax).

Comment: @mathguy - usually my preference too; I showed both then took that out just because you see Oracle using `to_date()` under the hood in the plan, which seemed to clash slightly with my point about `between` *8-)